# How to substitute rows only if a sequence condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I prepared a pandas df and now require help with data manipulation. Looking at the last column "Dig add", my goal is to find 10 elements in a row, within the same decade, for example from 180 to 189, then delete and replace them with a single row with the same data for all columns except "Dig add", where I need to put the same number without the last digit, for example 18.

The data in the columns "Tree", "Ton", and "Dest" must all be the same.

I don't know how to approach this issue

```
     Tree   Ton Dest    Dig_add
1    2      NAT BO02GNP 011
2    2      NAT BO02GNP 014
249  2      INT INTCH1  180
250  2      INT INTCH1  181
251  2      INT INTCH1  182
252  2      INT INTCH1  183
254  2      INT INTCH1  184
255  2      INT INTCH1  185
256  2      INT INTCH1  186
257  2      INT INTCH1  187
258  2      INT INTCH1  188
259  2      INT INTCH1  189
260  2      INT INTCH1  190
261  2      INT INTCH1  191
271  2      INT INTCH1  193
272  2      INT INTCH1  194
273  2      INT INTCH1  195
292  2      INT INTCH1  197
703  50     INT INTCH1  245
704  50     INT INTCH1  246
705  50     INT INTCH1  712
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description I assume that the `dig_add` can be divided by 10. We can create a new column with the new value and simply delete all duplicate values based on `Tree, Ton, Dest, and Digg_add_div`.

```
df['Dig_add_div'] = df['Dig_add'].astype(int) // 10
count_df = pd.DataFrame(df.value_counts(subset=['dig_add_div', 'Tree', 'Ton', 'Tree'])).rename(columns={0: 'count'})
count_df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
count_df = count_df.loc[count_df['count'] == 10]

# we know now which values are occuring 10 times. We can delete those from the initial dataset
df = df.merge(count_df, on=['dig_add_div', 'Tree', 'Ton', 'Tree'], how='outer')
index = df.loc[(df['count'] == 10) & (df.duplicated(subset=['dig_add_div', 'Tree', 'Ton', 'Tree']))].index
df.drop(index=index, inplace=True)
```

I hope this is the answer that you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to delete only rows that are in sequence of ten (180 - 189) and not others( 190 - 197).
I think the first step is to check if this condition is satisfied or not...
Furthermore elements of the last column are strings, so eventually in a new column I can add something like str[:-1]

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much.... Tomorrow I'll study every step in order to try to understand how it works
You save me a lot of time; I was trying to solve my issue using a set of  "for loops", splitting and checking the Dig-add...

Comment: Great to hear! Could you accept my solution?